# Strength of connection in between nodes

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, social-networking

How exactly do we measure the strength of a connection between 2 nodes on a social network graph. essentially between a node and its first degree connection, can we measure the strength of connection?

What exactly is meant by "strength of connection" on a social network analysis context.

I assume first degree connection implies if a--b--c then b is first degree connection of a and c is second degree connection of a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strength of connection between nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810191/strength-of-connection-between-nodes)

Comment: Please don't post another question if you don't get activity ont he original one. Try to improve its quality by editing it and making it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Connection node strength is the sum of
all neighboring link weights i.e. node degree with the addition of a weight that captures how strong the communication is. You can assign some arbitrary measure of communication between two nodes on a social network making it a weighted network.

[image: Calculation of node strength from node degree]

For example, the sum of inbound and outbound flights between Harare and Johannesburg makes up the weight of the established route (a fraction of all the routes that connect either of these two cities to the rest of the world) between the two cities.